# Incomplete upload ftp in c#

Tags: c#, upload, ftp

I would like to run the ftp from my C # application, but he drank a problem when sending I can not understand.

When I run the upload script, it is well connected to the server but it create an empty file.

Can you help me?

I use this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace FTPClasse
{
   class ftp
{
private string host = null;
private string user = null;
private string pass = null;
private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
private Stream ftpStream = null;
private int bufferSize = 2048;

/* Construct Object */
public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

/* Download File */
public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}

/* Upload File */
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}

/* Delete File */
public void delete(string deleteFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + deleteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}

/* Rename File */
public void rename(string currentFileNameAndPath, string newFileName)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + currentFileNameAndPath);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
        /* Rename the File */
        ftpRequest.RenameTo = newFileName;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}

/* Create a New Directory on the FTP Server */
public void createDirectory(string newDirectory)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + newDirectory);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}

/* Get the Date/Time a File was Created */
public string getFileCreatedDateTime(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + fileName);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
        /* Store the Raw Response */
        string fileInfo = null;
        /* Read the Full Response Stream */
        try { fileInfo = ftpReader.ReadToEnd(); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
        /* Return File Created Date Time */
        return fileInfo;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
    return "";
}

/* Get the Size of a File */
public string getFileSize(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + fileName);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
        /* Store the Raw Response */
        string fileInfo = null;
        /* Read the Full Response Stream */
        try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { fileInfo = ftpReader.ReadToEnd(); } }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
        /* Return File Size */
        return fileInfo;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
    return "";
}

/* List Directory Contents File/Folder Name Only */
public string[] directoryListSimple(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
        /* Store the Raw Response */
        string directoryRaw = null;
        /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
        try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
        /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
        try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
    return new string[] { "" };
}

/* List Directory Contents in Detail (Name, Size, Created, etc.) */
public string[] directoryListDetailed(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
        /* Store the Raw Response */
        string directoryRaw = null;
        /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
        try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
        /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
        try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
    return new string[] { "" };
}
}
```

}

here is my script

```
ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://*******.*******.fr", "*************", "************");
ftpClient.upload(filename, sourcezip);
string fileSize = ftpClient.getFileSize(filename);
ftpClient = null;
```

and the result on the server

[image: the result on the server]

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. You say it does not create an empty file but it does, I think maybe what you're trying to say is it doesn't upload the file, it just creates an empty file. Would it be right? Do you have any errors? Have you tried to debug it and step through your code?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't upload the file. I don't have errors on the FTP Server or on the application. The process run's very well and normally ends. (excuse me for my poor English)

Comment: Show the relevant code. Create a few lines that reproduce the problem, then start debugging from there.

Comment: The problem is that he is truncating every file he uploads by opening it with `FileMode.Create`.

Comment: @AdamKDean lol, well spotted.

Comment: It's amazing what a bit of manual debugging can do. :)

Comment: always same with FileMode.Open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed that in your upload method you're using `FileMode.Create`:

```
FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
```

Maybe you should change that to `FileMode.Open`?

```
FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);
```

---

Description of `FileMode.Create`:

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten.** This requires
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission.
>   FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not
>   exist, use System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew; otherwise, use
>   System.IO.FileMode.Truncate. If the file already exists but is a
>   hidden file, an System.UnauthorizedAccessException exception is
>   thrown.

Description of `FileMode.Open`:

> Specifies that the operating system should open an existing file. The
>   ability to open the file is dependent on the value specified by the
>   System.IO.FileAccess enumeration. A System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   exception is thrown if the file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks but  il would like upload any files. thus ineed to use 'FileMode.Create'. my problem is that my file si juste create and don't upload

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What your code does is uploads a blank file, that is how you've designed it. You pass it a filename and it truncates the `local file` and uploads the blank `local file`. It doesn't create a blank file on the remote server, it creates a blank file on the `local` machine and uploads it.

Comment: always sames with FileMode.open

Comment: @Atoxis probably because you're testing with the same file, which now is 0 bytes on your disk.